# How to optimize search in search box with suggestion drop down using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a search box to search name of people to add in a group. on ng-change event of that search box I am calling a method in which I am consuming a rest service which is returning me a very large array of length 20000+

```
$scope.items =[
               {'name': 'John'},
               {'name': 'Bob'},
               {'name': 'Galvin'},
               {'name': 'Julia'}.........];

   /* And the front end looks like this */

<div class="input-group input-group-sm search-control"> 
            <input style="height:40px" id="dropdownMenu1" type="text" data-toggle="dropdown" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" placeholder="Search Name" ng-model="query" ng-change="searchNames()"></input><span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
</div>

    <div class="dropdown dropdown-scroll">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="NameSearch" style="max-height200px; width:100%;top:0px;overflow-y: scroll; position:absolute; ">

    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat='item in items | filter:query'> <a href="#"> {{item.name}} </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now let's consider a case when user types 'j' in the input/search box, then the drop down should contain only those names which has 'j' in it. And you can see that I am using filter to get this done.

But the issue is, it's very very slow. So I am looking form the solution which can make searching fast.

Thanks

Comment: FYI - I didn't downvoted, but you're clearly not doing it right. You should use typeahead instead (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) and implement the **Asynchronous results** example on your site